# Custom NSTableViewHeaderCell

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I've created a custom NSTableViewHeaderCell class but I still have one issue with separators: How know if I am drawing the last column header or not?
Actualy I don't want to draw a separator for the last column but I didn't found a way to know it is the last one.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a subclass of NSTableHeaderCell, create one more property on it for a NSTableColumn. You can set this property as you create and set an instance of your subclass for each of your table's columns.

Now that your subclass instances know the table columns to which they belong, they can use this to determine the table view. From the table view, you can get an array of table columns, and if you compare a given table column to the lastObject value of that array, you should be able to tell if your header cell belongs to the last table column.

If you choose to enable reordering for your table columns, you may have some more coding to do, but this should get you started.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.